# Want to print all groups to which user belongs

Tags: django

```
**Models.py**

class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("accounts:login")


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255,unique = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode = True,unique = True)
    description = models.TextField(default = '')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name = "group")

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Group,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('groups:single',kwargs = {'slug':self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

**Views.py**

class ListGroups(ListView):
    model = Group

**Html code**

<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="list-group">
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <h2>Your Groups!</h2>

    {% if user.group.count == 0 %}
      <p>You have not joined any groups yet! <p>
    {% else %}
      {% for group in user.group.all %}
      <a class="list-group-item" href="{% url 'groups:single' slug=group.slug %}">
        <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">{{group.name}}</h3>
        <div class="list-group-item-text container-fluid">
          {{group.description|safe}}
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <span class='badge'>{{group.members.count}}</span>
                  member{{group.members.count|pluralize}}
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <span class='badge'>{{group.posts.count}}</span>
                  post{{group.posts.count|pluralize}}
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

According to me it should print all the groups and it's details to which current logined user belongs but it is not printing anything.I have no idea what is wrong in this code.I have tried some other approaches but nothing works.Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no variable named `user` in the template, hence all what you wrote will probably not work.

We can however obtain a list of `Group`s where the logged in user is member of, by first of all modifying the `ListsGroup` a bit:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ListGroups(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Group

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Group.objects.filter(members=self.request.user)
```

Now we can render this like:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="list-group">
  <h2>Your Groups!</h2>
    {% for group in object_list %}
    <a class="list-group-item" href="{% url 'groups:single' slug=group.slug %}">
      <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">{{group.name}}</h3>
      <div class="list-group-item-text container-fluid">
        {{group.description|safe}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class='badge'>{{group.members.count}}</span>
                member{{group.members.count|pluralize}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class='badge'>{{group.posts.count}}</span>
                post{{group.posts.count|pluralize}}
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  {% empty %}
    <p>You have not joined any groups yet! <p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: user variable in template refers to current logined user, then why it is not working? and moreover i want to print all groups and groups to which user belongs.@Willem Van Onsem

Comment: @AnuragKumar: no, normally you have only a `request` variable, and you can use `request.user`, but that would look, in my opinion, a bit "unelegant".

Comment: request.user and user give same thing in html template and even if i am using request.user then also it is not working, could you tell me why?